# How to pass an array with multiple mesh objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, mesh

I will parse an array which I created in the web worker, back to the main thread.
The array includes a high number of THREE.Mesh objects.
When I trying to stringify this array :

```
self.postMessage(JSON.stringify(mesh));
```

an error occurs: 
three.min.js:182 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '971E7ACA-8223-4A5C-9F2F-E7966B58265F' of undefined.

How can I handle this problem regarding mesh objects???

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, you can avoid stringifying the array and rely on the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) to handle that for you:

```
self.postMessage(mesh);
```

[See the example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage#Worker_code)

Comment: I tried this one but there is another error: **Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': An object could not be cloned.**

Comment: Do you have functions or other non-valid properties on your object? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035854/error-cloning-element-from-scope-while-using-angular-and-web-workers

Comment: Actually I have one function inside to manipulate some data: `self.onmessage = function (e)
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({transparent: true, opacity: 0.4});
        var mesh= [];                                                                                      for (var i = 0; i < e.data.length; i++)
        {....  mesh.push(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));}                                       function _transformCoordinates(coordinates) {
            some manipulation with coordinates...
        }
     self.postMessage(mesh);
};`

Comment: It doesn't look like you are sending the function with the mesh though, right?

Comment: This might be kind of crazy, but try: `self.postMessage(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mesh)));` This might be the best way to ensure that there are no functions on the mesh. Although it might not help performance-wise...

Comment: When I trying this I get this kind of error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FAFA3BEB-443D-423D-BC22-9A9E0DC6CD71' of undefined** Do you know what it means?